# Recover administrator locked system?

Tags: windows-8.1, password-recovery, guest-account

I have a system, which is actually locked with an administrator password, So the password is prompted every time when I do the following things,

- Try to install a new software.
- Try to empty recycle bin
- Try to delete the C: drive files

Looks like I am a guest user not sure though, I have forgot my password, **WITHOUT formatting** how can I regain the administrator rights in my system ?

Operating System Windows 8.1

Comment: Please let me know if you would need other details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows account passwords are stored in a file called `SAM`, stored in the system directory. This file is locked and inaccessible to you as long as Windows is running. You have multiple ways to retrieve it, the easiest of them is booting your computer with a Linux Live CD such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) (or with a Windows boot CD if you have one), grab the `SAM` file, and crack the passwords within using a windows account password cracker (which is perfectly legal anyway since it's your account and your system).

There are many good cracking softare for that purpose, like [L0phtcrack](http://l0phtcrack.com/) and [Cain & Abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html). You may also want to take a look on this simple [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Sam-to-Hack-Windows).

Another approach (perhaps easier) is to reset the password using a Windows disquette (if available). See this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/96630/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-windows-password-the-easy-way/) for the steps.

Comment: Alternative is to reset the password, which may be easier if the original password is long.